# Can I run .net core 2.2 AND .net core 3.0 in same project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I currently have a project built around .net core 2.2. But I need to use net core 3.0 as well. Are they mutually exclusive in a project or can I install both and they live happily ? I ask because I am using 3rd party controls that currently only work with 2.2, but I need 3.0 for SignalR.

Comment: You don't need .Net Core 3.0 for SignalR.  It's just an additional library -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: To answer your question -> No, you cannot use them in the same project.  You can have two different projects in the same solution that use different .Net Core Versions.  But again see my earlier comment about SignalR and .Net core 2.2

Comment: Thank you Tony! Not the news I was hoping for, but at least know which direction to take now.